# How to run hql script using spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have Hive Query script and wanted to run in command line mode in unix, is there any option available to run it in command line mode?

Comment: Could you please elaborate it further what you want to achieve and what you have done so far?

Comment: I want to write shell job which will take query from properties file and run it on Hive, Impala and SparkSQL. Here I am trying to create performance matrix for query in Hive, Impala and Spark?

Comment: So far I have written shell job which will take Query from properties file and running on to Hive and Impala, same query I want to run on Spark SQL. If you have any idea, help appreciated.

Comment: I am using cloudera hadoop CDH 5.10.x, and found documentation its not supported in this CDH version. Below is link for same. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/spark.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am using Cloudera Hadoop (5.10.x)and according to CDH 5.10.x documentation it documentation its not supported.
Below is link for same. 
cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/spark.html